# ContainerRequest Response abortWith aborting and not providing response

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have implemented Container Request and created filter method and i am trying to abort in case of authorization failure. I see that the application stops as expected but it is not returning any message to client. I was expecting 401 error but it just stops abruptly.

public class SecuredFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

    String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
         requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
    }

    String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();
    // [...]
    }
```

}

I am expecting to see 401 error not just stopping abruptly.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your issue, but `abortWith()` is a `void` method. You need to also `return` after calling it, otherwise the rest of the code will still be ran.

Comment: @Paul i tried even with return but still i am not getting 401 error. I get 500 which is not expected